# Is this function one-one and onto?

Tags: real-analysis

Consider $A=\{(x,y)\in \Bbb{R}^2 : x+y \neq -1\}$

Define $f:A \to \Bbb{R}^2$ by $$f(x,y)=\Big(\frac{y}{1+x+y},\frac{x}{1+x+y}\Big)$$
Then is it one-one on A and is it onto?

The jacobian of f has non zero determinant on A, therefore inverse function theorem assures that $f$ is locally one-one, but is it globally one-one on A? 
And it looks onto if we think each component to be similar to function $1/x$.

Comment: Is easy check that f is injective because if f(x,y)=(0,0) then y=x=0

Comment: @vvnitram That argument only works for *linear* functions.

Comment: @vvnitram That would prove that $f$ is injective if $f$ was linear. $f$ is not linear.

Comment: Note that $\frac{y}{1+x+y}+\frac{x}{1+x+y}$ is never equal to $1$. So can it be onto?

Comment: @Neeraj I think what Thomas is trying to convey is the following: Look at $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$. If $f$ was onto there there would exists an $(x_{0},y_{0}) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$ such that $f(x_{0},y_{0}) = (\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$. This says, $\frac{x_{0}}{1+x_{0} + y_{0}} = \frac{y_{0}}{1+x_{0}+y_{0}} = \frac{1}{2}$ which on adding gives $\frac{x_{0}+y_{0}}{1+x_{0}+y_{0}} = 1$ which is not possible.

Answer (score 3):

Onto is pretty much answered in comments, so here is one-one.  If $f(x_1,y_1)=f(x_2,y_2)$ then
$$\frac{x_1}{1+x_1+y_1}=\frac{x_2}{1+x_2+y_2}\ ,\quad
  \frac{y_1}{1+x_1+y_1}=\frac{y_2}{1+x_2+y_2}\ .$$
Adding the equations,
$$\frac{x_1+y_1}{1+x_1+y_1}=\frac{x_2+y_2}{1+x_2+y_2}\ ;$$
multiplying out the denominators and noting that $(x_1+y_1)(x_2+y_2)$ can be cancelled,
$$x_1+y_1=x_2+y_2\ .$$
Substituting this back into the first pair of equations gives $x_1=x_2$ and $y_1=y_2$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f(x,y)=(a,b).$ Then as Thomas Andrews noted, $a+b-1 \neq 0.$ However we may with this condition solve for $x,y$ in terms of $a,b$ and get
$$x=\frac{b}{a+b-1},\ \ y=\frac{a}{a+b-1},$$ so it appears $f$ is injective.

Note injectivity here follows since there is only *one* pair $(x,y)$ for each pair $(a,b)$ in the range $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{x+y-1=0\}.$

Answer (score 0):

I think $f$ is one-one but $not$ onto.

Let $(a,b)\in \mathbb{R}^2$. Then for $f$ being onto we must have $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $f(x,y)=(a,b)$. If you will solve this condition then you will get that $x=\frac{b}{1-(a+b)},y=\frac{a}{1-(a+b)}$. Thus you can get all the values in $\mathbb{R}^2$ except those on the line $x+y=1$. You can then check that there are indeed $no$ such points in the plane whose function value lies on that line. Thus $f$ is not onto.

For seeing that $f$ is one-one, suppose $f(x,y)=f(p,q)$. Then by solving the corresponding condition you will get that $\frac xy=\frac pq$. Thus $f$ can fail to be one-one only on the line $y=mx, m\in \mathbb{R}$. But then if you will calculate the value of the function on $y=mx$, then you will see that $x=p$ and hence $y=q$, thus confirming that $f$ is one-one.

Comment: I think $x$ numerator is $b$ not $b(b-1).$

Comment: @coffeemath :- you are right. thanks for the correction. i have edited the answer.

Comment: Also I think you have signs reversed on $x,y$ (denominators should be $a+b-1$ where yours is $1-(a+b).$ This is really not much of an issue, the point being one can solve and only assuming $a+b $ is not $1.$